# sorting json using php

Tags: php, json

I'll try to sort a json format file  by date and time

I try this method.

```
    function sortFunction( $a, $b ) {
        return strtotime($a["date"]) - strtotime($b["date"]);
    }

 $inp = file_get_contents('del.json');
$tempArray = json_decode($inp);
usort($tempArray, "sortFunction");
var_dump($tempArray);
```

del.json

```
[{"date":"2013-09-01 00:00:02","content":"1"},{"date":"2013-09-01 00:00:09","content":"5"},{"date":"2013-09-01 00:00:01","content":"3"}]
```

and ill get this error 
`Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`
Thanks in advance!

I use this method and its work thanks to all your comment sorry i'm new bie hehe!

```
   function my_sort($a, $b)
    {
        if ($a->date < $b->date) {
            return -1;
        } else if ($a->date > $b->date) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0; 
        }
    }

    usort($users, 'my_sort');
```

Comment: Your code is wrong here. PHP will not allow json-like direct declaration. Post your actual code, please.

Comment: [I cannot reproduce it](http://3v4l.org/mkP5D). As far as I know, your code triggers a parse error even in PHP 5.5. Is this your *real* code?

Comment: If you are getting json then use json_decode($data) before processing it

Comment: The array is malformed. AS @ÁlvaroG.Vicario said you should have a parse error. Take a look at error_reporting level

Comment: Whatever, I guess it's duplicate of [Access JSON object name in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479033/access-json-object-name-in-php). Please have a look at it.

Comment: sorry that may original code i edit it! hope you help me thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two changes will make sence:

```
function sortFunction( $a, $b ) {
    return strtotime($a->date) > strtotime($b->date) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

or

```
$tempArray = json_decode($inp, TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't understand the sort callback.

It's return value increases or decreases the index of the actual element (by +1 or -1).

http://php.net/usort

> The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or
>   greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be
>   respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

The second thing is, your json array gets decoded with an numeric array which is sorted by default

```
$tempArray[0] = ...
$tempArray[1] = ...
$tempArray[2] = ...
```

Important for the sorting callback is the KEY, not the values of your array.

Steps to make it work:

1. Decode the JSON array into PHP array
2. Put the Date, converted to DateTime object into the key

   `// Pseudo code:`

   `$tempArray[DateTime Object] = Array(values);`
3. use the usort with callback comparing the Date (`>`,`<`) instead of subtracting one by another (this is a semantical / logical error you have).

Tho, it would be **easier** to convert the Dates into unix timestamp and simply use `natsort()` on the array.